# How to sum up over array objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i got 3 arrays in my java script code:

```
arr1 = [ { _id: '1', sum: 100 }, { _id: '2', sum: 100 } ]

arr2 =  [ { _id: '1', sum: 281.16 }, { _id: '2', sum: 863.93 } ]

arr3 = [ { _id: '1', sum: 80 },  { _id: '2', sum: 220 } ]
```

What I now want is an array which contains the key ID´s an the sum of all values fitting to the key.

So this 3 arrays returns the following:

```
giveMeArray = [{_id: 1, sum: 461.16} , {_id: 2, sum 1183.93}]
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

ok my mistake... i thought that would be clear:

the arrays have not the same length. and same content. SOORRY

arr1 = [ { _id: '1', sum: 100 }, { _id: '2', sum: 100 }, { _id: '3', sum: 100 }  ]

arr2 =  [ { _id: '1', sum: 281.16 }, { _id: '2', sum: 863.93 } ]

arr3 = [ { _id: '1', sum: 80 },  { _id: '4', sum: 220 } ]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow? What language are you working in?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker `i got 3 arrays in my java script code:` You should tag your javascript in your post though.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: It clearly says javascript in the first line of the question

Comment: Sorry-- was hard to read before the edit.

Comment: I would suggest, if you had the possibility, that you check out the Underscore or the Lo-Dash libraries. They have excellent support for dealing with these kinds of problems.

Comment: It sounds like you have an idea already: "with forEach over each array?" why don't you investigate that possibility a little more?

Comment: thanks for the edit. im new here. dont knew it better. but i hope i could point out the problem. my englosh is bad too but ill do my very best. :)

Comment: yeah I tried it with foirEach. but i get always the same massage that this obj has no method foreach

Comment: @DennisKaikowski I edited my answer below to take into account that your arrays can be different sizes. Check it out, I think it should work how you want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `forEach`, use [the `reduce` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do sums:

```
var giveMeArray = [arr1, arr2, arr3].reduce(function(m, a) {
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        m[i].sum += a[i].sum;
    return m;
}, [{_id:'1', sum:0}, {_id:'2', sum:0}]);
```

Disclaimer: Only works if all arrays contain the objects in the same (by _id) order and are not sparse. If you need such, it gets a little more complicated:

```
var sumsById = [arr1, arr2, arr3].reduce(function(m, a) {
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        m[a[i]._id] = (m[a[i]._id] || 0) + a[i].sum;
    return m;
}, {});
var giveMeArray = [];
for (var id in sumsById)
    giveMeArray.push({_id: id, sum: sumsById[id]});
giveMeArray.sort(function(a,b){return a._id-b._id;});
```

Comment: thank you. w try it now. can need a while :)

well... i tried... but  i have more than 2 elems in the arrays and i do not have in every array the same id. in one i have an _id : 3

in an other i dont have this but i have an _id: 4

must work...

Comment: o thank you very much! this has helped me a lot. need so time to debug in my head but it works very n1!! so thankk you!

Answer (score 0):

A nested `for` loop and a pre-defined end object can get the trick done:

```
var mainArr = [arr1, arr2, arr3];

var arrObj = [{_id:1,sum:0},{_id:2, sum:0}];

for (var i = 0; i < mainArr.length; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < mainArr[i].length; k++) {
        arrObj[k].sum += mainArr[i][k].sum;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/4UzQT/

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Changed this to take into account that arrays can be different sizes.

```
//Merge arrays into 1
var arrTotal = arr1.concat(arr2);
arrTotal = arrTotal.concat(arr3);

var arr1Max = arr1[arr1.length - 1]._id;
var arr2Max = arr2[arr2.length - 1]._id;
var arr3Max = arr3[arr3.length - 1]._id;
//Get highest ID value (4 in our case)
var max = Math.max(arr1Max, arr2Max, arr3Max);

var newArray = new Array();

for(var i=1; i<=max; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var j=0; j<arrTotal.length; j++) {
        if(arrTotal[j]._id == i) {
            sum += arrTotal[j].sum;
        }
    }
    newArray.push({ _id: i, sum: sum });
}

//Display all ID sums (4 in our case)
for(var i=0; i<max; i++) {
    alert(newArray[i]._id + ", " + newArray[i].sum); 
}
//1 = 461.16 //2 = 963.93 //3 = 100 //4 = 220
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NCzNn/1/)